# Why do I get an error with a foreach loop inside a while loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, collections

The quick program I made for Problem 7 on Project Euler keeps producing an error.

I am unfamiliar with Java. I transferred my Python code for Problem 7 into Java, just to see if I could do it. I am teaching myself Java to get ahead of the game.

The code for my Python program is:

```
no = 2
print(3 % 2)
primes = [2]
while len(primes) != 10001:
    no = no + 1
    no2 = 0
    for each in primes:
        if no % each != 0:
            no2 = no2 + 1
            if len(primes) == no2:
                print(primes[-1])
                primes.append(no)
print("Final answer is: " + str(primes[-1]))
```

The code for my Java program is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class P7Euler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int no = 2;
        int no2 = 0;
        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        primes.add(2);
        while (primes.size() != 20){
            no = no + 1;
            no2 = 0;
            for(int i : primes){
                if(no % i != 0){
                    no2 = no2 + 1;
                    if(primes.size() == no2){
                        System.out.println(primes.get(primes.size() - 1));
                        primes.add(no);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println("The final answer is: " + primes.get(primes.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at Test1.examples.P7Euler.main(P7Euler.java:16)
```

EDIT: The code was wrong, the for loop I originally used is now there.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Is this really java code?

Comment: @A4L I think it's Java 8 and its "lambdas" (they preferred that over unsigned support (sight))

Comment: I'm not sure if you're explicitly copying the code but the error your getting is because you're adding to the list while you are iterating through it with a for each loop. Use a typical `for(int iter = 0; iter < length; iter ++)` format and you won't get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I assume the correct syntax for the loop is `for(int i : primes){`.

You cannot modify a list while iterating through the elements using a foreach loop. Try using a `java.util.ListIterator` to add to the list while iterating:

```
for (ListIterator<Integer> listIterator = primes.listIterator(); listIterator.hasNext();) {
     int i = listIterator.next();
     if(no % i != 0){
         no2 = no2 + 1;
         if(primes.size() == no2){
              System.out.println(primes.get(primes.size() - 1));
              listIterator.add(no);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I knew that, look at the edit at the bottom. I tried your code and it worked.Thanks a lot! Comarki.

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` loop will use an `Iterator` to go through your list, forbidding the change you're trying to make with `primes.add(no)`.

As your list is an `ArrayList`, you can access the `i-th` element at no additional cost with `primes.get(i)` and the size by `primes.size()`. An easy way out would be:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < primes.size(); idx++){
    int i = primes.get(idx);
    if (no % i != 0) {
        no2 = no2 + 1;
        if(primes.size() == no2){
            System.out.println(primes.get(primes.size() - 1));
            primes.add(no);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry this was the original code for the loop for(int i : primes){

Answer (score 0):

You may not modify a `Collection` in an enchaned `for` loop (or in any other for that matter)